# Unable to get IMailFolder.MessageLabelsChanged Event to fire

Tags: mailkit

1) With a Free Gmail account were unable to get the MessageLabelsChanged  event to fire.  We're assuming this should occur when you take a gmail message and add or remove a label from it.

At the same time, we ARE able to get the Idle, CountChanged, MessageExpunged and MessageFlagsChanged events working..

We are calling it on the Service.Inbox object.

We found this link https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/208 about wrong event raised.  Our labels are very uniquely named, therefore we believe, they should not be confused with events?

2) What is the ImailFolder.Subscribed method do?  Should this be called to solve issues #1???

Many thanks Jeffrey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should probably remove the LabelsChanged event from ImapFolder because GMail is not very good about sending those notifications to the client (in fact, I'm unable to get GMail's IMAP server to send them either).

I've mostly kept it for completeness in case GMail's IMAP is ever fixed to reliably send those notifications.

Comment: I thought we were doing something dumb. Its too bad that its broken.  Should we report it to google.. They do have  a bug tracker and apparently do fix things like this.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=label%20imap

Comment: I guess the only way to do this would be to use their REST api.  Which apparently has support for this.   - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list

Comment: @jstedfast Is there a way to get notifications about changes on Gmail Labels? Does this method work now after 4 years?

Comment: Nope, GMail is still terrible